# IIS DotNetNuke website, other Applications not working

Tags: .net, iis-7.5, dotnetnuke

I have 15-20 applications in my Default Web Site, which are working fine. I configured DNN 07.03.02 as Default Web Site, and DNN works fine. But the applications are getting errors

"Could not load file or assembly 'DotNetNuke.HttpModules' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to dedicate a website for your DNN in IIS instead of configuring the default website on its folder.
Your problem could result of a cascading of web.config files: the one in the root folder of your DNN and the other in your applications roots folder. When you run on of your applications, the web.config of DNN is also loaded, including the registration of the HttpModules.

Comment: are there any other option?